# Including resources in swift package manager manifest

Tags: swift, objective-c, bundle, swift-package-manager

I am porting an objective c cocoa pod over to swift package manager. It has a bundle of fonts in the package. In the original pod spec, there was a link of code that created the bundle.

```
  s.resource_bundles = {
 'mathFonts' => [ 'fonts/*.otf', 'fonts/*.plist' ]
```

}

In the swift package, I created a static bundle, called mathFonts.bundle and added it to the package as shown below.

[image: structure of the swift package]

in the manifest file, I tried to copy the resources as shown below:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "iosMath",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v8)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "iosMath",
            targets: ["iosMath"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [

    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "iosMath",
            resources: [.process("mathFonts.bundle")]), // **<- this is where I am adding the resources**
        .testTarget(
            name: "iosMathTests",
            dependencies: ["iosMath"],
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("iosMath")// 5
             ]),

    ]
)
```

I'm getting a runtime crash here:

```
return [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"mathFonts" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

When I manually copy the bundle into the directory of the project that I am importing this package into, it works just fine. How do I include this bundle so that it is made accessible when the package is installed?

Comment: You should reference to resource bundle in packages in Swift with `Bundle.module`.

Comment: The library is in objective-c

Comment: I haven't tried it in Objc, may be it will also work, if not you can create Swift wrapper for accessing it.